# why cannot sf object use all data.table methods in R?

Tags: r, data.table, r-sf

I am learning sf in R. Since I like data.table very much, I though I could use both. However, it seems that sf object deriving from data.table cannot use methods in data.table any more. Following is an example:

First I generate a very simple `data.table` and make it to a `sf` object. So far so good.

```
> dfr <- data.table(id = c("hwy1", "hwy2"), 
+                   cars_per_hour = c(78, 22),
+                   lat = c(1, 2),
+                   lon = c(3, 4)) 
> my_sf <- st_as_sf(dfr , coords = c("lon", "lat"))
```

Then I check the structure of the `my_sf`. It is an `sf` object, a `data.table` and a `data.frame`.

```
> str(my_sf)
Classes ‘sf’, ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id           : chr  "hwy1" "hwy2"
 $ cars_per_hour: num  78 22
 $ geometry     :sfc_POINT of length 2; first list element:  'XY' num  3 1
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "id" "cars_per_hour"
```

Then I tried some arbitary function `unique`, and it does not work. Actually this `my_sf` does not work as data.table at all.

```
> my_sf[, unique(id)]
Error in unique(id) : object 'id' not found
```

Does anyone know the reason for it? Is it not possible to use `data.table` for `sf`?

Comment: Notice that `dfr[,unique(id)]` works as intended.  Can you provide more details on the function `st_as_sf`? From which package it comes from?

Comment: Related reading: [compatibility with sf library](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2273), and links therein.

Comment: @DJJ It is from the package `sf`. It is used for spatial analysis.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the function `st_as_sf` has destroyed .internal.selfref attribute turning back the data.table into `data.frame` although the class name has been preserved.

```
> str(dfr)

#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  4 variables:
#$ id           : chr  "hwy1" "hwy2"
#$ cars_per_hour: num  78 22
#$ lat          : num  1 2
#$ lon          : num  3 4
#- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

`setDT(my_sf)` might be enough to turn back the data.frame into a `data.table`

Comment: If I just simply convert it back to data.table, I cannot use it as sf anymore...

Comment: Ok then I suggest taking a look at the link that @Henrik posted. As far as I understand, for now you cannot retain both features for now. So it will depend on what you want to do next with the data. Bear in mind that you can still do most of the manipulation as a data.frame.

Comment: That is true. It is still compatible with `tidyverse`.